Why did the Luna 25 lander fail to land on the moon?
On August 19, 2023, the Russian Luna 25 lander crashed into the moon whilst attempting to land at the lunar south pole. What went wrong and why did this happen?

Well, it did land, didn't it?

@JonCuster it did! It just failed to stay in one piece

More like the ground is hard.

It is true that nothing walked away from the landing, so it wasn’t a ‘good’ landing.

This was caused by an onboard control unit not receiving the needed data from one of the lander's accelerometers. According to ROSCOSMOS on Telegram:

"This did not allow, when issuing a corrective pulse, to record the moment the required speed was reached and to timely turn off the spacecraft propulsion system, as a result of which its shutdown occurred according to a temporary setting,"

In other words, it was unable to detect when it reached the correct speed. This caused a burn that should have taken 84 seconds to take 127 seconds which had the effect of sending the lander on a crash trajectory. (source)
